# I need help getting information on multiple info windows on google map!! markers appear but no info?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

ok here is my issue, I'm using google maps API, and I have added markers to all the locations needed, but now I'm trying to implement info windows, I got only one info window to work but it does not display the full information on the array object, it only displays the address and location but no mater what marker I click on the same info window appears, if anyone have any suggestions are welcome.

here is my code

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 33.672340,
    lng: -117.849041
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatLng
  });


  var locations = [];

  locations.push({
    name: "Pelican Hill Golf Club",
    address: "22800 S Pelican Hill Rd, Newport Beach, CA 92657",
    web: "golfpelicanhill.com",
    phone: "(866) 921-3139",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.587368, -117.843351)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Costa Mesa CC",
    address: "1701 Golf Course Dr, Costa Mesa, CA 92626",
    web: "costamesacountryclub.com",
    phone: "(714) 540-7500",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.668630, -117.926816)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Coto de Caza Golf & Racquet Club",
    address: "25291 Vista Del Verde, Coto De Caza, CA 92679",
    web: "coto-de-caza.com",
    phone: "(949) 858-4100",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.593684, -117.582163)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Escena",
    address: "1100 Clubhouse View Drive, Palm Springs, CA 92262",
    web: "escenagolf.com",
    phone: "(760) 778-2737",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.837302, -116.496758)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "The Reserve Club",
    address: "74001 Reserve Dr, Indian Wells, CA 92210",
    web: "thereserveclub.com",
    phone: "(760) 568-5599",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.689647, -116.364011)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Iron Wood Country Club",
    address: "73735 Irontree Dr, Palm Desert, CA 92260",
    web: "ironwoodcountryclub.com",
    phone: "(760) 346-0551",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.688658, -116.377234)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "BIGHORN",
    address: "255 Palowet Dr, Palm Desert, CA 92260",
    web: "bighorngolf.com",
    phone: "(760) 341-4653",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.681487, -116.397590)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Indian Wells",
    address: "46000 Club Dr, Indian Wells, CA 92210",
    web: "indianwellsclub.com",
    phone: "(760) 345-2561",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.716594, -116.329313)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Catalina Island Golf Course",
    address: "1 Country Club Dr, Avalon, CA 90704",
    web: "visitcatalinaisland.com",
    phone: "(310) 510-0530",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.336750, -118.331057)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Lake Tahoe Golf Course",
    address: "3021 US-50, South Lake Tahoe, CA 96150",
    web: "tahoeparadisegc.com",
    phone: "(530) 577-2121",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(38.830537, -120.031264)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Black Bear Golf Club",
    address: "24505 Calusa Blvd, Eustis, FL 32736",
    web: "blackbeargolfclub.com",
    phone: "(352) 357-4732",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(39.506252, -107.722317)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "ASU Karsten Golf Course",
    address: "1125 E Rio Salado Pkwy, Tempe, AZ 85281",
    web: "asukarsten.com",
    phone: "(480) 921-8070",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.374342, -111.868505)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "The Wynn Golf Club",
    address: "3131 S Las Vegas Blvd, Las Vegas, NV 89109",
    web: "wynnlasvegas.com",
    phone: "(702) 770-3575",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(36.128339, -115.164919)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Hidden Lakes Golf Course",
    address: "35 Fairgreen Ave, New Smyrna Beach, FL 32168",
    web: "hiddenlakesgolfclub.com",
    phone: "(386) 427-4138",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(37.528020, -96.718455)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Glen Dornoch Waterway Golf",
    address: "4840 Glen Dornoch Way, Little River, SC 29566",
    web: "glensgolfgroup.com",
    phone: "(843) 249-2541",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.807309, -79.044356)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Causeway Club",
    address: "10 Fernald Point Rd, Southwest Harbor, ME 04679",
    web: "thecausewayclub.org",
    phone: "(207) 244-3780",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(44.292062, -68.331503)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Lions Municipal Golf Course",
    address: "2901 Enfield Rd, Austin, TX 78703",
    web: "austintexas.gov",
    phone: "(512) 477-6963",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(30.290959, -97.777061)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Blue Ash Golf Course",
    address: "4040 Cooper Rd, Cincinnati, OH 45241",
    web: "blueash.com",
    phone: "(513) 686-1280",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(39.247544, -84.393563)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "SilverRock Resort",
    address: "79-179 Ahmanson Ln, La Quinta, CA 92253",
    web: "silverrock.org",
    phone: "(760) 777-8884",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.667301, -116.280366)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Santa Ana CC",
    address: "20382 Newport Blvd, Santa Ana, CA 92707",
    web: "santaanacc.org",
    phone: "(714) 556-3000",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.665493, -117.887574)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Newport beach Golf Course",
    address: "3100 Irvine Ave, Newport Beach, CA 92660",
    web: "newportbeachgolfcoursellc.com",
    phone: "(949) 852-8681",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.660791, -117.878921)
  });

  locations.push({
    name: "Desert Willow",
    address: "38-995 Desert Willow Dr, Palm Desert, CA 92260",
    web: "desertwillow.com",
    phone: "(760) 346-0015",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(33.765671, -116.366058)
  });
  /*
  locations.push({name: "", address:"", web:"", phone:"", latlng : new google.maps.LatLng()});
  */

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i].latlng,
      map: map,
      title: locations[i].name
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i].address
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

    });

    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize);

  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: SORRY YOU DO NEED TO ADD YOUR API KEY!!!

Comment: An API key is not required, but key=API_KEY generates an error.  I removed that from the posted code.

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7hd6n433/) based on the [indicated duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) adjusted for the minor differences required by your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
locations.forEach(function(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location.latlng,
      map: map,
      title: location.name
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: location.address
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

    });

  }
});
```